# Call .phtml file from CMS block - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I want to call a .phtml file from CMS block.
The file contains a script for Mailchimp popup.
My file located at:
/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/popup.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="your_block_identifier" template="../Magento_Catalog/templates/product/popup.phtml" }}
```

Comment: It didn't work. This is what worked: {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="popup" template="Magento_Catalog::product/popup.phtml"}}